# How can I download iCloud app data to PC?

Tags: applications, icloud

I have app data in iCloud. I would like to download it to a PC laptop. Specifically this is the Audio Memos app, and I would like to save the recordings to computer and delete them from iCloud. I do not have access to the device.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Apple developer account, you can access your iCloud data from [**developer.icloud.com**](https://developer.icloud.com/).

---

*Since it's behind developer authentication, I'm not going to say any more, other than behind this button is what you're looking for…*

[image]